# Do the same lame settings (--alt-preset standard) have differrent names?

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, lame

I've always used windows, and therefore EAC to rip my CDs, but since I've started using Ubuntu more often, I decided to try to rip some albums there.

I ended up using k3b (since I found it in the Ubuntu Software center. Tried to install RubyRipper first, but when 'sudo apt-get install ' or UDC fails, a Windows user like me is lost)

The real question here is about the settings for the lame encoder. I'm used to just writing --alt-preset standard, and everything works like a charm, but the default in k3b look like this:

```
lame -r --bitwidth 16 --little-endian -s 44.1 -h --tt %t --ta %a --tl %m --ty %y --tc %c --tn %n - %f
```

I assume these are some sensible lame settings, and not a malicious perl script (although it looks like it). It seems to me like some of these ought to be there, and that I can not overwrite the whole thing with my good ol' --alt-preset.

So, the question is do I need to replace anything, or is -h the same as old --alt-preset?
Is it a difference between '--preset standard' and '--alt-preset standard'? 
And are those the same as -V 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - -h isn't the same as the old alt-preset, the alt-presets are now just aliases for the preset options, which just map to the various -V options.